# Working with Worksheets in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

This might be very simple to some ...but will change my world if I can figure this out.

I have a master worksheet (dashboard) that is linked to other worksheets (worksheet 1, worksheet 2 etc.) within the same workbook.  If I add another sheet I have to go through the entire sheet and link it to my master worksheet (dashboard).

My question is how can I copy all of the information from Worksheet 1 to worksheet 2 and still have it connect to master worksheet (dashboard)?

Example:

Worksheet 1 has sales information for certain product.  Key components are connected to the dashboard (product name, quantity, margin, exchange rate etc.).  All of this information is linked to row 1 in master workbook.  Worksheet 2 is linked to row 2 etc.

The master workbook (dashboard) has totals and other calculations.  If I want to add another worksheet #3 - which would go to row 3 ...how can I do this without having to manually link all of the cells?

I hope someone can help me with this!

Thank you!

From a novice excel person :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't ***add*** a new sheet; ***copy*** an existing one. 
Right-click on the tab, select "Move or Copy...", select "Create a copy",
select where you want the new sheet to go
("(move to end)" is what you probably want), and click "OK".

Answer (score 0):

Say you call your worksheets "ProductA", "ProductB", "ProductC".

On your dashboard you have something like one row about each product:

```
=ProductA!A1      =ProductA!B1 
=ProductB!A1      =ProductB!B1 
=ProductC!A1      =ProductC!B1
```

to pick up cells A1 and B1 of the ProductA, ProductB, ProductC tabs.

When you add a new tab, ProductD, make sure everything is in the same place as on ProductA, B, C tabs.  (eg copy ProductA by right-click-on-tab-and-do-move-or-copy-and-choose-copy-tickbox and then rename it as ProductD, so you know it's all the same.)

Then copy your ProductC line on your dashboard, to get:

```
=ProductA!A1      =ProductA!B1 
=ProductB!A1      =ProductB!B1 
=ProductC!A1      =ProductC!B1
=ProductC!A1      =ProductC!B1
```

Then select that bottom line, do Ctrl-H (find-and-replace), type "ProductC" in the top box and "ProductD" in the bottom box, and it'll change them all.

---

Alternatively, have an extra column on one end of your dashboard (you can always then hide it out of sight), where you type the tab name, and use INDIRECT.  If these three are columns A, B and C, then:

```
=INDIRECT(C1&"!A1")      INDIRECT(C1&"!B1")      ProductA
=INDIRECT(C2&"!A1")      INDIRECT(C2&"!B1")      ProductB
=INDIRECT(C3&"!A1")      INDIRECT(C3&"!B1")      ProductC
```

Then when you add in ProductD tab, just end a new line, write ProductD in that right-hand column, and copy the formulae down and they'll all work instantly.

---

However...

Bear in mind that if you've got yourself in a situation where you have tons of sheets, one for each product, then you may not have structured your file so well.

A different structure you could consider is:

- Have a single data table that holds all your data for all products in a really basic table-of-data format
- Have the dashboard link to that, either directly, or via a pivot table.

This way you only have three tabs - Dashboard, PivotTable, and Data.  All your data goes on one table, you don't have to maintain umpteen identical product sheets that all need changing if anything needs to be updated.  And if the Product sheets are actually useful in their own right, not just to create the dashboard, then have just one Product tab, with a cell at the top where you choose the product name, and have it filter the data on that one product sheet accordingly.

Pretty much all of that is probably achievable with a Pivot table.